# Teradata join with SCD type 2

Tags: sql, teradata, scd

How to join transaction table and SCD table to get records from SCD according to date of transaction.

```
Select A.id, A.trans_dt, trans_amt, B.pmt_meth
from trans1 A
left join scd1 B
  on A.id=B.id
```

Now I need to get pmt_meth for each transaction. so pmt_meth for first 2 transaction should be "M" and for last transaction it should be "P"

This is creating duplicates due to join issue (i know that) but not sure how to match dates so that no duplicate will be created and I will get desired result

```
create table scd1 (id integer, pmt_meth varchar (10), start_dt date, end_dt date)

Insert into scd1(1, P, '2015/06/30', '2017/05/30')
Insert into scd1(1, M, '2017/05/30', '2019/07/31')
Insert into scd1(1, P, '2019/07/31', '2050/12/31')

Create table trans1 (id integer, trans_dt date, trans_amt float)
Insert into trans1 (1, '2019/07/25', 100)
Insert into trans1 (1, '2019/07/01', 120)
Insert into trans1 (1, '2019/07/31', 50)
```

Now I need to get pmt_meth for each transaction. so pmt_meth for first 2 transaction should be "M" and for last transaction it should be "P"

```
Select A.id, A.trans_dt, trans_amt, B.pmt_meth
from trans1 A
left join scd1 B
  on A.id=B.id
```

Expected result is

```
id trans_dt      trans_amt    pmt_meth
1  '2019/07/25'  100            M
1  '2019/07/01'  120            M
1  '2019/07/31'  50             P
```

Comment: Why should the last be 'P'?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the date condition in the `on` clause:

```
Select A.id, A.trans_dt, A.trans_amt,
       B.pmt_meth      
from trans1 A left join
     scd1 B
     on A.id = B.id and
        A.trans_dt bewteen b.start_dt and b.end_dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is based on an inclusive-exclusive interval:

```
Select A.id, A.trans_dt, trans_amt, B.pmt_meth
from trans1 A
left join scd1 B
  on A.id=B.id
 and A.trans_dt >= B.start_dt 
 and A.trans_dt < B.end_dt
```

The same logic is applied for the OVERLAPS operator

```
Select A.id, A.trans_dt, trans_amt, B.pmt_meth
from trans1 A
left join scd1 B
  on A.id=B.id
 and (A.trans_dt, NULL) OVERLAPS (B.start_dt, B.end_dt)
```

Btw, Teradata supports *Temporal Tables* (in Teradata plus Standard SQL syntax) to implement SCD2 in a simplified way.